# Postgresql stored procedure not running from script

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have several stored procedures in a postgresql database that are run from a python script.  They are all executed in the same fashion, and they all work except one.  That stored procedure works fine, if I run it from from a query tool in pgAdmin, but it does nothing when it runs from the script.  It doesn't give an error; it just doesn't do anything.  It is supposed to delete an entry from one table and update a field in another table.

Here is a gist for the stored procedure: https://gist.github.com/algaspar/e7cb4157d2f3f70f8b47439e2a4058a4

Here is a gist for the script: https://gist.github.com/algaspar/3fa548379203aff9d887caed3c92cb64

I've trimmed the script down to what isn't working.  Basically, it reads in a file with a number of items and builds a list that it passes to the stored procedure with executemany (my sample just builds a list without reading a file, but it doesn't work any better :( ).  I can run the procedure in query tool with:

```
CALL close_item('item1', CURRENT_DATE);
```

and it does what it is supposed to do--delete an entry from the itemchanges table and update a field in the itemhistory table.  Does anyone have an idea why I shouldn't be able to run this stored procedure from a script?

Thanks--

Al

P.S.
I'd really like to get an answer to this; so I'm not making this **THE** answer.  I can solve my problem by running SQL in executes inside a loop.  This accomplishes, what I need (decided CURRENT_DATE was fine so the list would only have items now):

```
       for item in my_list:
           cursor.execute ("DELETE FROM itemchanges WHERE item = %s", (item,))
       ps_connection.commit()
       for item in my_list:
           cursor.execute ("UPDATE itemhistory SET fixed_date = CURRENT_DATE WHERE item = %s AND fixed_date IS NULL", (item,))
       ps_connection.commit()
```

I'd like to know, though, why calling the stored procedure with an executemany didn't work, when the stored procedure worked just fine as a query...

Answer (score 0):

The commit was needed; I missed putting it in my gist.  Thanks!

My problem, though in my "real" script was that my items were being read in from a file, but in my gist example I was building the list manually.  When I read the items in from the file, I was getting 'XXXXXX\n' rather than just 'XXXXXX'.  I changed where I added them to my list to be item.rstrip(), and my stored procedure works fine now from cursor.executemany():

```
    for item in input_file:
        load_tuple = (item.rstrip(), today)
        item_list.append(load_tuple)
    run_SQL(item_list)
```

Bottom line, I wasn't comparing apples to apples when I debugged; I need to pay more attention.